# Creating a symlink of directory inside home

Tags: linux, symlink

I have the following /home directories:

> /home/user
>
> /home/files

I'm trying to create a symlink of `files` inside `user`, but the command `ln -s files user/files` results in a broken link. Also using the graphic interface, opening the context menu on any directory inside home shows `Make Link` option disabled.

Does linux not support such a link?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `ln -s files user/files` will create a link to `files` *relative to the current location* . So if you’re currently in `/home/user`, it will create a link to `/home/user/files`.

Also, your second parameter says that you want the link filename to be `user/files`, which doesn’t make sense. (Although filenames with dashes are theoretically possible, they are hard to handle. And this isn’t what you want anyway.)

The (relevant variant of the) synopsis of the `ln` command is:

```
ln -s TARGET LINK_NAME
```

So, what you want is:

```
ln -s /home/files /home/user/files
```

This would create an absolute link. If you’re currently in `/home/user`, you can also do

```
cd /home/user
ln -s /home/files files
```

This would also create an absolute link, but you could omit the absolute path of the link location, as you’re already in the same directory.

You could also create a relative link.

```
cd /home/user
ln -s ../files files
```

Relative links make sense when you plan tossing a directory structure around. For example, relative links are commonly used when deploying software projects.

Comment: I was already in home as I did `cd ..` prior to the link command. However it seems that calling the command from inside the `/user` folder works as expected